# Grouping with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to group by "date" an object like this:

```
let myObj = [
  {"date":"01/12","Deposits":50000},
  {"date":"01/12","Withdrawals":10000}
]
```

So if I did groupBy "date", I'd want to receive:

```
[
  {"date":"01/12", "Deposits":50000, "Withdrawals":10000}
]
```

I tried many different ways without success =(

Comment: You need to provide your attempt(s)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach without lodash, by using `.reduce()` and the spread syntax `...` to extract your wanted properties. By using `.reduce()` you can group your array's objects into a larger aggregation object (ie: the `acc`), which you can then get the `values()` of to get your array of results:

```js
const myObj = [{"date":"01/12","Deposits":50000},{"date":"01/12","Withdrawals":10000}];

const res = Object.values(myObj.reduce((acc, {date, ...rest}) => {
  acc[date] = {...(acc[date] || {date}), ...rest};
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

If you wish to use lodash, here is an approach using `_.groupBy()`, `_.map()`, `_.assign()` and `_.flow()` which will allow you to make your own function to merge arrays by a key:

```js
const myObj = [{"date":"01/12","Deposits":50000}, {"date":"01/12","Withdrawals":10000}];

const mergeArr = _.flow(
  arr => _.groupBy(arr, 'date'),
  group => _.map(group, arr => _.assign({}, ...arr))
);

const res = mergeArr(myObj);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.assign(...arr)` will mutate the 1st object in the array. Change it to `_.assign({}, ...arr)`.

Comment: @OriDrori thanks for pointing that out. I've updated it to use `{}` so it won't mutate the object anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = _.map(_.groupBy(myObj, 'date'), value => _.assign(...value));
```